# memory keep increasing when looping in shell script under CentOS6.5

Tags: linux, shell, loops

I have written a shell script to monitor my service to keep it alive.
But it's strange that the memory usage keep increase in my monitor script.
Do anyone have any idea about what's going on?

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
export PATH
monitor=$1

start() {
....
}

watchdog() {
    while [ $monitor == 1 ]
    do
        count=$(ps -Al | grep xxxxx | wc -l)

        if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
            timestamp=$(date)
            echo "[$timestamp] shutdown unexpectedly, restarting now..." >> $LOG
            echo $?
            start
        else
            sleep 10
        fi
    done
}

watchdog
```

The count usually is bigger than 0, and the memory usage increase even it always goes to else case.
[image]
You can see watchtas memory usage is keep growin.

Comment: Show how you have determined the memory usage. And are you talking about the overall system memory usage, the memory usage of the script, or the memory usage of the application that is being started? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm using a python file to determine how many memory my script used. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py it contain private and shared memory usage.

Comment: We don't know what that script does. So don't make us work it out. Tell us exactly what it is telling you and why you think it is your script that is causing the problem.

Comment: That script shows the sum of private and shared memory usage of the process. I always use that script to check if my program have memory leak. I think the line count=$(ps -Al | grep xxxxx | wc -l) is the reason memory increasing, but I don't know why.

Comment: Did you try this on another system (not CentOS)? Can you run this from `ksh`  or `zsh` on the same system, do you still get the same issue? AND agree with above comments, please improve your Q with small samples of data that support your Q (don't answer in comments). Good luck.

Comment: Get rid of counting process `xxxxx` and go with a simpler `if pgrep -f xxxxx > /dev/null; then`. This is not the root cause though. You are possibly leacking memory elsewhere in the script, or the python script you are running is mis-calculating the memory footprint. `echo $?` will always return 0 unless the previous line `echo .... >> $LOG` fails.

Comment: I use valgrind to detect script which only contain simple loop, and it show there are memory leak. I think it maybe leaking in loop until the process is done, so I guess I need to think another way to do watchdog.